How should examples be formatted for one-shot or few-shot prompting when using OpenAI's structured output?
When using OpenAI's structured outputs, should the examples in one-shot or few-shot prompting follow the JSON format of the structured output before parsing?
For example, consider the code below using one-shot prompting:
from pydantic import BaseModel
from openai import OpenAI

client = OpenAI()

class CalendarEvent(BaseModel):
    name: str
    date: str
    participants: list[str]

completion = client.beta.chat.completions.parse(
    model="gpt-4o-2024-08-06",
    messages=[
        {"role": "system", "content": "Extract the event information."},
        {"role": "system", "content": "Alice and Bob are going to a science fair on Friday."},
        {"role": "system", "content": '{"name":"Science Fair","date":"Friday","participants":["Alice","Bob"]}'},
        {"role": "user", "content": "Charlie is going to a concert on Saturday night."},
    ],
    response_format=CalendarEvent,
)

event = completion.choices[0].message.parsed

In this example, the prompt "Alice and Bob are going to a science fair on Friday." is accompanied by a corresponding output:
{"name":"Science Fair","date":"Friday","participants":["Alice","Bob"]}
My question is: Do the examples need to be structured in JSON format like this, or can they be presented in another format? What are best practices?

You typically don't need to provide one-shot or few-shot examples when using structured outputs. By passing a model as response_format=CalendarEvent, you're already including the model's information into the final prompt.
You can improve it by adding descriptions to the model and its fields as they also get included in the final prompt.
class CalendarEvent(BaseModel):
    """Calender event description"""
    name: str = Field(..., description="The name or title of the event")
    date: str = Field(..., description="The date of the event as a weekday")
    participants: List[str] = Field(..., description="A list of participants' names")

Though if you do want to use one-shot or few-shot prompts the above JSON format is appropriate but consider improving your system messages with Labels like below
messages=[
    {"role": "system", "content": "Extract the event information."},
    {"role": "system", "content": """Examples:
                                        User: Alice and Bob are going to a science fair on Friday.
                                        Response: {"name":"Science Fair","date":"Friday","participants":["Alice","Bob"]}"""},
    {"role": "user", "content": "Charlie is going to a concert on Saturday night."},
]

